# how to write a bash script to execute multiple bash scripts?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am new to bash shell scripting and I need guidance to **write a bash script** which will **execute other multiple bash scripts or php scripts**. If you can help me on this I will be very thankful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani very basic stuff, like, echo, simple 'if else', simple 'function' etc

Comment: Having one script execute another is simply a matter of using the file name of the other script as a command - as long as its execution bit is set, and the file can be found. What is your problem with that?

Comment: Calling a external script is like calling `echo`. Just make sure the called scripts are either in the current path or you call them by full name _/path/to/script.sh.

Comment: I apologize to you, for troubling you guys with so simple stuff. But now I understood how it works. Thank you for your kind responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most basic example `vi test.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
./test2.sh
```

`vi test2.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi there"
```

`test.sh` when executed will execute `test2.sh` (and expects it in the same path as `test.sh`).

Comment: got it. thank you so much for your help. ❤

Comment: Why use `sh` here? IMHO it would be better to ensure that `test2.sh` is executable and let its shebang take care of what interpreter to use

Comment: very basic I said :=)